# Oracle Date and Time Conversion

Tags: oracle, types, union

I have a problem with the `SELECT` statement below:

```
SELECT SO FROM ORDERS 
UNION ALL 
SELECT SO FROM QUOTES
```

When I run the query I get the error `Fields must have same data types`. I understand that there is data conflict between the field `SO`. In the `Orders` table it is of `NVARCHAR2(50)` whereas the `Quotes` table is composed of the `Integer` datatype. Is there any workaround to make a union with the field `SO` as shown in the above statement without changing the data type of the field `SO`?

Any help here is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

It is just like the query shown below

```
select 1 from dual    --integer datatype
union all
select '1' from dual  --varchar2 datatype
```

In order to make this work ,you need to change the INTEGER DATATYPE to VARCHAR

```
select to_char(1) from dual  --change the datatype to CHAR in Quotes table 
union all
select '1' from dual         -- this remain unchanged
```

Your final Query will be like

```
SELECT SO FROM ORDERS
UNION ALL
SELECT TO_CHAR(SO) FROM QUOTES
```

Comment: Thanks Gaurav. I was searching in Google and i found some thing like CAST statement. I did like this CAST (SO AS INTEGER).It works for me but i am not sure if this the right way of doing. Could you please throw some light on this.

Comment: @santhosha: either way is fine.